# Does Twitter Bootstrap support AddThis buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

I can't seem to get my AddThis buttons to show in my bootstrap page.  Are there known problems with this.  I can't seem to find any instances of this on the web.
The instructions from addthis are to post the code anywhere within the page which I have done.

Code below:

```
            <head>
            <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

            </head>
            <body>
        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_32x32_style" style="left:50px;top:50px;">
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4fd7a2f13ac8bb1a"></script>
        <!-- AddThis Button END -->
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Properties For Rent</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
             <br/>
              <br/>
               <br/>
            <div class="container">

            <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Welcome to rentraro.com</h1>
            <p>The premier property management and holiday home rental accommodation specialists operating in Rarotonga, <br/>  the main island and gateway to the beautiful Cook Islands.</p>
            <p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
            Learn more
            </a>
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                      <li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="img/heritage_48_md.jpg" alt="">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h4>The Heritage</h4>
                            <p>Your piece of paradise awaits...</p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="img/highland_ocean_view_02_md.jpg" alt="">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h4>Highland Ocean View</h4>
                            <p>Some of the best views on the island...</p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="img/reiihana's_06_md.jpg" alt="">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h4>Reihana</h4>
                            <p>Muri Beach at your doorstep...</p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a> 
                          </div>
                           <li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="img/Kite_Moana_02_md.jpg" alt="">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h4>Kite Moana</h4>
                            <p>Simplicity in sought after Muri...</p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
            </div>

        </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Haven't come across this problem. Can you post up some code and maybe create the issue as a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the file needs to be hosted on a webserver for the AddThis links to show. Doh.